# How can I efficiently retrieve all possible values of the 'subjects' property from an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I had an object with this structure:

```
[
  {
    "event_id": 1,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Physics"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Psychology"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 2,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Maths"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 3,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What will be the fastest way to get all possible values of subjects prop in this option? Is this only possible to achieve by looping through each single sub-object and push value to "counting array" if it not already there?

Comment: Please share with us your attempts to reach your goal, and explain where you stuck on in order to help us help you debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most readable way would indeed be to loop through the subjects and add them to the array if they don't exist.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "event_id": 1,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Physics"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Psychology"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 2,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Maths"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 3,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const all = []
for (const { subjects } of data) {
  subjects.forEach((s) => {
    if (all.indexOf(s.name) === -1) {
      all.push(s.name)
    }
  })
}
console.log(all)
```

Another useful way is to use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to deduplicate the values in the array.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "event_id": 1,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Physics"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Psychology"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 2,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Maths"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 3,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const all = []
for (const { subjects } of data) {
  subjects.forEach((s) => {
    all.push(s.name)
  })
}
const s = [...new Set(all)]
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

just because there's several ways to do the same things, here's one with `reduce`

```
data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    accumulator.push(currentValue.subjects.map(x => x.name));
    return [...new Set(accumulator.flatMap(x => x))];
}, [])


// will output
// ['Chemistry', 'Physics', 'Psychology', 'History', 'Maths', 'Biology', 'Geography']
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    "event_id": 1,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Physics"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Psychology"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 2,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Maths"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 3,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    accumulator.push(currentValue.subjects.map(x=>x.name));
    return [...new Set(accumulator.flatMap(x=>x))];
}, []));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
  {
    "event_id": 1,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Physics"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Psychology"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 2,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Maths"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chemistry"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 3,
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Biology"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Geography"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const allSubjects = data.map(x=> x.subjects).reduce((a,x) => [...a, ...x] ,[]);
const uniqueSubjects = allSubjects.filter((e,i) => allSubjects.findIndex(a => a.id == e.id) == i);

console.log(allSubjects, uniqueSubjects);
```